# Getting error TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null as function is called for the second time

Tags: typeerror

I am using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var testValue = document.getElementById("test").value;  
    document.getElementById("test").value = ++testValue;
    var testValue2 = document.getElementById("test").value; 

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        alert("3");
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"; 
        alert("4");
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
  }
  alert("1");

document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block"; 

alert("2");
xmlhttp.open("GET","catalog/view/theme/default/template/information/latest_newsroom.php?q="+testValue2,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<form name="testForm" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="1"  />
    <input type="button" name="testButton" value="More" onclick="loadXMLDoc()"  />
</form>
```

and it gives the error :

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

as my function runs for the second time.

Answer (score 1):

The error is corect.

You have set `var testValue = document.getElementById("test").value`;

so this `document.getElementById("test").value = ++testValue;`

should be `testValue.value = ++testValue;` since `testValue` is now a variable.

Below is what i have sugested in the comment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var testValue = document.getElementById("test").value;  
    document.getElementById("test").value = ++testValue;
    var testValue2 = document.getElementById("test").value; 

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        alert("3");
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"; 
        alert("4");
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
    else
     {
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
     }
  }
  alert("1");    


alert("2");
xmlhttp.open("GET","catalog/view/theme/default/template/information/latest_newsroom.php?q="+testValue2,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<form name="testForm" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="1"  />
    <input type="button" name="testButton" value="More" onclick="loadXMLDoc()"  />
</form>
```

Comment: but this part is working fine                                           I am getting the problem at this part fo the code                         alert("1");

document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block"; 

alert("2");  , alert 2 works for the first time, but second time, code runs till alert 1 only, this is the url :                       http://elite.weexcel.in/elite/index.php?route=information/newsroom

Comment: Try moving this: document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block"; inside an else for this document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"; Otherwise both statements try to set the value.